# What Mathematical Formula Expresses the Highest Rate of Growth?

Tags: functions

I'm conflicted between an exponential growth function such as n^x 
or something like x^x? Also can it be proven that it is the fastest function for growth?

Comment: There is no formula with the highest rate of growth, probably. I can't imagine it would be difficult to take any formula that is proposed to be the highest, and just make it grow faster by, say, composing it with itself for instance.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Or $\times\;2$ :P

Comment: Exponentials are near the beginning of the [lists of scales used to classify growth of fast growing functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy).

Comment: If $f(n)\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$ then $g(n)=nf(n)$  grows faster than $f(n).$ And $h(n)=f(n)^{f(n)}$ grows much faster. And if you have a family $F=\{f_j:j\in \Bbb N\} $of functions then $g(n)=n(1+\max \{|f_j(n)|:1\le j\le n\})$  grows faster than any member of $F.$

Answer (score 1):

A fun fact is that there are functions that grow so fast they can't be computed. A simple example is Radó's [Busy Beaver function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver) $\Sigma$. It's value is known only for $n \le 4$, and that $\Sigma(5) \ge 4098$ and $\Sigma(6) \ge 3.515 \cdot 10^{18267}$

Answer (score 0):

Let us take natural log of each function and compare their rate of growth.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d}{dx}\ln{\left(n^{x}\right)}&=\frac{d}{dx}x\ \ln{\left(n\right)}\\
&=\ln{\left(n\right)}\\
\\
\frac{d}{dx}{\ln{\left(x^{x}\right)}} &=\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\ln{\left(x\right)}\right)\\
&=\ln{\left(x\right)} + 1
\end{aligned}
$$

Thus the rate of growth of $n^{x}$ is higher for $x<\frac{1}{e}n$, the rate of growth of $x^{x}$ is higher for $x\geq\frac{1}{e}n$.